# localStorage in Firefox extension throws "The operation is insecure." exception

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, local-storage

I am developong Firefox Add-on that uses localStorage to store user data in website context. It access localStorage via injected content scripts using standard methods:

```
localStorage.getItem(key);
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

The code that calls localStorege is injected to website via PageMod:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
    contentScriptFile: [
        self.data.url("app.js")
    ]})
```

When methods getItem/setItem are called, security exception is thrown:

> [Exception... "The operation is insecure."  code: "18" nsresult:
>   "0x80530012 (SecurityError)"  location: ""]

So far I did not find out the reason why this is happening. I have an suspicion that it may have something to do with old FireFox bug, but probability is low: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2012/04/25/firefox-failing-localstorage/

Maybe anyone could suggest an idea what could cause a problem?

**Additional info:**

- We are using Addon SDK 1.16
- Problem occurs since FF 29.0 RC1 (everything works with FF 28)

Comment: I couldn't produce this exception with Aurora (30) or Nightly (31)

Comment: Yup, we're in the same boat.  Broken for 29, fine for Aurora and nightly.  I suspect this is a bug in FF29.

Answer (score 3):

We also have an extension and are getting the same error with local storage.  This is a bug with 29, as @basarat notes this error should only be thrown for CORS issues.  We've tested with Aurora and Nightly with no issues either.  We're filing a bug with Mozilla.

Answer (score 3):

As previously noted, this is a bug in Firefox 29 and should be resolved in version 30: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=980023

For the time being, you can work around this issue by reassigning the localStorage object used in your content script:

```
var localStorage = unsafeWindow.localStorage;
```

Answer (score 0):

`The operation is insecure.` should only be thrown when you load a JavaScript file cross domain. To enable is operation as secure the domain serving the JS file must enable CORS : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: This is tricky part, because in this case JavaScript file is loaded from browser resources. 
E.g. URL resource://my-extension/data/js/extension.js

Also same error is thrown, when CORS is disabled in Firefox

Comment: This is not true. It also happens when you access person data (localstorage, cookies etc..) when the user has denied access in their browser.